# Eclipse Dependencies in MANIFEST.MF

Tags: eclipse, plugins, dependencies, required, manifest.mf

I'm new to this group.  Thanks for any help.

I'm using Eclipse and subversion (svn) in the work environment.  I imported project A from the svn and renamed it to project B using Refactor. I also updated the .project file. Then I clicked MANIFEST.MF on project C and opened the Dependencies tag, I wanted to add project B to the "Required Plug-ins" window.  However, project B is no where to be found.

What am I missing?

TennFest

Comment: Eclipse has some bugs when renaming projects, etc. Try rebuilding the projects. Sometimes just closing and opening them helps. Also restarting eclipse.

Comment: Is your project A available in the Dependencies tab? Perhaps, the renaem refactor didn't update your manifest file as well?

Answer (score 0):

Only plugin type projects can be added to plugin dependencies, so project B should have also manifest.md file and generally be a plugin project. In case You want to use standard java project, pack it to a jar and link the jar to bundle classpath